# Redirect home page to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I only want to redirect **one page**, my **homepage**, to some **subdomain**.

I addded these lines in my `.htaccess` files,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} #some rule
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://subdomian.mydomain.com
```

But, something went wrong - here's the warning in error log:

```
RewriteRule: bad argument line '^'
```

How can I correct the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, if that is exactly what it looks like. So, your final rule should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://subdomian.mydomain.com [R=301]
```

Note that you should also include the 301 redirect flag.

Comment: You beat me to it. =) @fish, the 301 HTTP code indicates a permanent redirection, that will be cached in the browser with no expiry date set unless the original page itself expires from the cache. That'll result in one less hit on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but i do believe you need to mark your RewriteRule for external redirection even if it's a subdomain.

Try the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://subdomian.mydomain.com [R]
```